# Finish the powershell script

Tags: powershell

I have had difficulty trying to finish this script. Bascially I would like to check the memory left, check the top 3 memory hogs, show when the last reboot was, show the last update, show services that are automatic but have stopped and show how much room hdd space I have on the server.

```
Write-Host "Getting the information required" -ForeGroundColor green
Function Get-Checks {
  $Output = "C:\users\b2badmin\desktop\checklist\check$((Get-Date).ToString('MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss')).txt"
  #Get the computer name
  $env:computername | out-file -Append $Output
  #Show Available memory
  Get-Counter -ComputerName localhost '\Memory\Available MBytes' |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty countersamples |
    Select-Object -Property Path, cookedvalue |
    Out-File -Append $Output
  #Show the processes that are using the most resources top 3
  Get-Process | Sort-Object -Descending WS |
    select -First 3 |
    Format-Table -Property WS,ProcessName |
    Out-File -Append $Output
  #Show last reboot
  Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem |
    select csname, @{LABEL=’LastBootUpTime’;EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}} |
    Out-File -Append $Output
  #Show the last installed Hotfix for windows updates
  Get-HotFix | Select -Last 1 |
    Format-List -Property InstalledOn,Description,HotfixI |
    Out-File -Append $Output
  #Get the services that are Automatically started and list them if they are stopped
  Get-WmiObject Win32_Service |
    Where-Object { $_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' -and $_.State -ne 'Running' } |
    Format-Table -AutoSize @('Name' 'DisplayName' @{Expression='State';Width=9} @{Expression='StartMode';Width=9} 'StartName') |
    Out-File -Append $Output
  # Show how much room is left on the HDD
  Get-WmiObject Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName Localhost |
    Format-Table DeviceID, MediaType,
      @{Name="Size(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f ($_.size/1gb))}},
      @{Name="Free Space(GB)";Expression={[decimal]("{0:N0}" -f ($_.freespace/1gb))}},
      @{Name="Free (%)";Expression={"{0,6:P0}" -f (($_.freespace/1gb) / ($_.size/1gb))}} -AutoSize |
    Out-File -Append $Output
```

I keep getting a `>>` prompt. What do I need to complete the script so that it runs?

Comment: You are simply missing the `}` at the end of the function to close it.
You also have to call the function in order for it to run.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, as David said it correctly, you are missing a closing bracket at the end of your code }. I tried debugging it an got that issue.

P.S. Try adding Set-PSDebug mode on with following command.

**Set-PSDebug -Trace 1**

This will help you diagnose your script better. :)

Comment: Awesome thanks for the tip just a quick question about the debugging are the "Debug:     1+" is that the line that it is refering to?

Comment: Yep, that's right, it states, DEBUG:    1+  >>>> Set-PSDebug -Trace 1 which means, the debug mode is on. While this is on, you may notice that it will give description after every part of the script is executed. In-case if you wish to disable it, just replace -Trace 1 with -Trace 0, hope it helps. :)